# Get ActionDescriptor from WebApi MessageHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

how can i retrieve ActionDescriptor from a MessageHandler ?

I'm able to get the ContractDescriptor in the SendAsync method using this code:

```
var config = request.GetConfiguration();
_controllerSelector = config.Services.GetService(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector)) as IHttpControllerSelector;
HttpControllerDescriptor descriptor = _controllerSelector.SelectController(request);
```

But i don't know how to get the ActionDescriptor.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension from System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions:

```
//using System.Net.Http;

var actionDescriptor = request.GetActionDescriptor();
```